# Beginning Objective C Code errors? What's wrong?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, error-handling

I just began a series of tutorials in Objective C as my first serious programming language to learn (I have a very basic and fragmented knowledge of Android). I am following a series of tutorial videos and have come across code sprinkled with errors. The author of the tutorials uses the same code flawlessly. I am new to Objective C, so I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code. Here it is:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


//-----interface-----
@interface Person: NSObject{
int age;
int weight;
}
-{void} print;
-{void} setAge: {int} a;
-{void} setWeight: {int} w;
@end



//-------implementation-------

@implementation Person
-{void} print{
NSLog(@"I am %i years old and weigh %i pounds", age, weight);
}
-{void} setAge: {int} a{
age=a;

}
-{void} setWeight: {int} w{
weight=w;
}

@end

int main{int argc, char *argV[]}{
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
Person *amrit;

amrit = [Person alloc];
amrit = [amrit init];

[amrit setAge: 16];
[amrit setWeight: 125];
[amrit print];
[amrit release];

[pool drain];
return 0;


}
```

Comment: You need to go through some basic books and tutorials.  the basic syntax is off.  It's (void), not {void}.  It's (int) not {int}.  Print should should be %d, not %i - etc... Very, very basic stuff.

Comment: I recommend you go through books and ask specific questions with road blocks you hit.  Also, make sure you're specific about what error/issue you're hitting.  Just not a code drop with what am I doing wrong ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-{void} print;
-{void} setAge: {int} a;
-{void} setWeight: {int} w;
```

Return type and argument type should be enclosed in `()` and not in `{}`. The same when you are doing the implementation too.